# Is there any way to change word to another word depends on the condition inside the word?

Tags: c#, regex, replace, split

I want to change my word to another word, depends on the conditions. What is the best way to do it.

***Original word-with MINUS value***

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "MY_TEST_SEQUENCE" MINVALUE 8 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 11  CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE
```

***Result-1***

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "MY_TEST_SEQUENCE" MINVALUE 8 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 8  CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE
```

***original word-with PLUS value***

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "MY_TEST_SEQUENCE" MINVALUE 8 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 11  CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE
```

***result-2***

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "MY_TEST_SEQUENCE" MINVALUE -8 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 999 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE
```

***Conditions:***
In above example has two result and two original words...

***Conditions are;***

1. if MINVALUE has plus value (8) than make **start with** value same as 
   MINVALUE (8)...
2. if MINVALUE has minus (-8) value than make **start with** value same as MAXVALUE (999)
   MINVALUE...

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's being asked here. If you could flesh out your question with _why_ you need to do this, or an outline of the larger problem you're trying to solve, it would give us some context to work with.

Comment: Please post the c# code you've written so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are after, but here is something:

```
var startvalue = 0;
if(MINVALUE > 0)
{
    startvalue = MINVALUE;
}
Else if(MINVALUE < 0)
{
    startvalue = MAXVALUE;
}

var result = String.Format(@"CREATE SEQUENCE ""MY_TEST_SEQUENCE"" MINVALUE 8 MAXVALUE 999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH {0}  CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE",startvalue)
```

Some more clarification of your question would allow for more useful answers.

Comment: It say MAXVALUE and MINVALUE doesnt exits in the context?

Comment: I'm not going to code this for you. You need to write code to extract the current values from the text you are using. Read up on String.IndexOf

Comment: Ok I will check it out. Thansk